# What are the repercussions of a DDoS attack on a website?

Tags: ddos

First of all, I'd like to know what exactly a DDoS attack is- my understanding is that it's a collection of infected or "zombie" computers, all controlled by a central computer, with the intent of overloading the website, and making it inaccessible and / or slowing the service down to 90's dial up levels (a.k.a. unusable).

How can one prevent it? I understand that those annoying CAPTCHAs are used, but is there actually a way to prevent one manually?

How well do third-party security services, such as cloudflare or fire eye, work? Are there ways to beat them?

What are the repercussions of a DDoS attack? If a website is DDoS'd, are passwords / credit card / bank data stored in the database compromised? Are certain pieces of encrypted data now at risk of exposure?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do major sites prevent DDoS?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/how-do-major-sites-prevent-ddos)

Comment: CAPTCHAs are normally used to prevent automated spambots, not to prevent DDoS.

Comment: You're asking quite a few questions here. I'm concerned that this may be too broad, but each of your individual questions (how to prevent DDoS? / how (well) do CDNs mitigate DDoS and how might they fail? / what is the scope of harm from a DDoS?) seems fine. I'd suggest limiting it to one question and asking the others separately.

Comment: For prevention: [DDoS - Impossible to stop?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/33811/13146) and [What techniques do advanced firewalls use to protect against DoS/DDoS?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/114/13146) Also: [How does CAPTCHA mitigate DDoS attacks?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/22906/13146)

Comment: Have you done any research on these questions? These are pretty easily answered with a couple search queries.

Comment: related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/81258/66382

Answer (score 2):

All a denial of service attack (of which a DDoS is a specific type) does is deny legitimate users access to the site. Anything further is a separate attack. Any repercussions are just those arising from the site no longer being accessible to legitimate users for a time (*availability* being one of the three pillars of security, which is why this is a security issue even though there is no data breach and no malicious users get control of the site).